# How to convert panda series index date into DatetimeIndex?

Tags: python, pandas

The following data below is from a pandas series, but I need the date converted to DatetimeIndex like this format: 2020-08-17. The index of this series should be a pd.DatetimeIndex. What are some ways to convert it as such?

```
8/17/20    14082780.0
8/18/20    14277100.0
8/19/20    14483216.0
8/20/20    14685442.0
8/21/20    14886403.0
Length: 212, dtype: float64
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change the index to be as type of datetime:

```
df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index)
```

More generally for a non-index column:

```
df['Date']= pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])
```

Comment: Thank you, Noah! That worked! I appreciate your help. Take care.